# Error in getDate() on angular2 / 4

Tags: angular, typescript, timestamp, getdate

I'm using Angular 4 but I have a problem getting the date from an input...

I'm using "angular2-datetimepicker" (view here --> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker) so I can set the time too

this is my html:

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="fromDate" [settings]="settings"></angular2-date-picker>
```

and this is in my component.ts

```
settings = {
    bigBanner: true,
    timePicker: true,
    format: 'M/d/yyyy hh:mm',
    defaultOpen: false
  };
fromDate: Date;
```

Then, I want to convert the variable `fromDate` to timestamp format; I tried using this, but it not worked:

```
Math.floor(this.fromDate.getTime() / 1000).toString();
```

In console it shows me this error

```
'fromDate.getDate is not a function ... ...'
```

Is there any other way to get the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `date: Date = new Date();` 
or it seems fromDate property contains a string, and not a Date object,you can test it with Date, something like : `new Date('2017-03-08T00:00:00+01:00')`